# When to use WCF Fault Exception

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, fault

I have a simple WCF service that carries out a simple operation:

```
[OperationContract]
DoSomething (Stuff input);
```

If an exception occurs inside `DoSomething` then a `FaultException` will be returned. Given that all the client needs to know is whether something went wrong, would you say that there's no need to define a `FaultException` in this scenario?

Comment: Handling Exceptions and Faults -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789039.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is always good practice to return a `FaultException`, since if you do not, the **channel will be faulted** and cannot be used again.

The decision what information need to be sent to the client is taken in the configuration (in service behaviour):

```
         <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="myName">
                     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
       // ....
```

In fact I always implement [`IErrorHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) behaviour on the service to catch all exceptions and return `FaultException<T>` so that I do not have to do it in all my operations.