# WCF method return type when adding new entities

Tags: .net, wcf, validation

I'm completely new to WCF.

I'd like to hear your thoughts on setting the return type of service methods which adds new content on the host server.

I need to let the client know if the user e-mail address already exists, otherwise continue on. Would you prefer a boolean or an exception (what about unintentional exceptions then)?

The thing is, that numerous validation criteria's might be added in the future and I also need to know the newly generated user id, if the insertion was completed succesfully.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a result class, which you return from the `CreateSomething()` method, and throw a `FaultException` when something went wrong:

```
public AddMemberResult AddMember(Member member)
{

    // check all input, create the member

    if (allGood)
    {
        return new AddMemberResult { UserID = createdMember.ID };
    }
    else
    {
        throw new FaultException<AddMemberError>(new AddMemberError(errors));
    }
}


class AddMemberResult
{
    public int UserID { get; set; } 
}

class AddMemberError
{
    public AddMemberError(List<Error> errors)
    {
        Errors = errors;
    }

    List<Error> Errors { get; set; }
}

class Error
{
    public int Code { get; set; }   
    public string Description { get; set; } 
}
```

Of course you can simply return an `int` from `AddMember()`, but using a class as return type you can apply versioning without having to update all clients. If you were to add a new property, say `boolean IsActivated` which you also want to return, you can simply create a property for that in the `AddMemberResult` class, without breaking existing clients.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer CodeCaster

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with exceptions.

As you say, you need to return an id, so that is the proper return type from the service when called successfully.

If called unsuccessfully, you will need to know information about what went wrong. This is what exceptions are for. They can contain lots of information.

Answer (score 0):

Don't throw exceptions because it will cause the channel fall into the **FAULT** state, which means that if you use a session, you will have to re-create a new connection to the server. This would lead to inefficient communication.

I would create a data contract which inherits from **IExtensibleDataObject**

For instance,

```
[DataContract]
    public  class Result:IExtensibleDataObject
    {
        [DataMember]
        public bool Created { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Guid NewID { get; set; }

    }
```

For future expansions, you can apply data contract versioning to your class depending on the scenario you have (schema validation required/ not required). More information is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733832.aspx)

Comment: As I read in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514470/when-to-use-wcf-fault-exception, it's my understanding that using FaultExceptions does not cause the channel to fall into the FAULT state?

Comment: It will cauze the channel to be FAULT. You can test it really easily using a console application and throw the exception. Next, try to reuse the channel.